# Merge element if dates overlap

Tags: php

i want to merge some element of an array :
- If dates overlap then merge element :

For example :

Array :

id : 1
start_date : 05/05/2016
end_date : 10/05/2016
quantity : 5

id : 2
start_date : 12/05/2016
end_date : 12/05/2016
quantity : 20

id : 3
start_date : 09/05/2016
end_date : 15/05/2016
quantity : 50

id : 4
start_date : 05/05/2016
end_date : 10/05/2016
quantity : 100

id : 5
start_date : 01/08/2016
end_date : 01/08/2016
quantity : 10

1st parse :

id : 1
start_date : 05/05/2016
end_date : 15/05/2016
quantity : 155

d : 2
start_date : 12/05/2016
end_date : 12/05/2016
quantity : 20

id : 5
start_date : 01/08/2016
end_date : 01/08/2016
quantity : 10

2nd parse :

id : 1
start_date : 05/05/2016
end_date : 15/05/2016
quantity : 175

id : 5
start_date : 01/08/2016
end_date : 01/08/2016
quantity : 10

I hope i'm clear.
Actually For make this i need a while loop and 2 foreach but it's so expensive.
What is the best way to do this in php ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can take the smallest day and highest day of each month in you dates, then all dates that has a day between smallest and highest have to be merge. you can end up with one loop

Comment: Hello, no it'snt works, for exemple

id 1 => start_date : 05/05/2016 end date 05/05/2015
id 2 => start_date : 15/05/2016 end date 25/05/2015
id 3 => start_date : 08/05/2016 end date 08/05/2015

I can't merge because no dates overlap

Comment: Ah sorry maybe i misunderstand the problem.you can start by selecting the date that has highest difference between start and end date, then merge with it all dates that have end date in its interval.Then repeat same steps but without previous dates